# Move end of filename to beginning on OSX El Capitan

Tags: regex, macos, terminal, rename, file-rename

I've got a few thousand files in a few folders with names like so:

```
filename #1.mp4
filename #1.mp4
.
.
.
filename #5555.mp4
```

Is there a way to move the #number part to the beginning of the filenames in bulk, on a mac? So the result would look like:

```
 #1 filename.mp4
 #2 filename.mp4
 .
 .
 .
 #5555 filename.mp4
```

So far I've tried two pieces of software, Renamer for Mac and Namechanger for Mac. Neither have the option to do what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `rename` utility (perl based) you can do:

```
rename 's/^(.+)\s+(#\d+)/$2 $1/' *.mp4
```

If `rename` is not available then use `sed`:

```
for f in *.mp4; do
    mv "$f" "$(sed -E 's/^(.+) +(#[0-9]+)/\2 \1/' <<< "$f")"
done
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for answering. The rename isn't available. The second script seems to be running but the files are not renamed in the folder. Any ideas why?

Comment: More quoting was needed. Try my updated rule in the directory where your `*.mp4` files are located.

Comment: I always recommend using `mv's `-i` option for bulk renames like this, in case any filenames happen to match after the renaming. Without `-i`, one of each matching pair of files will be deleted without even a notification.